# `dpkg --configure -a` hangs

Tags: configure, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I update, I got the following message

```
$ sudo apt-get update
....
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Following the error message, I try

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
setting up snapd (2.14.2~16.04) ...
```

then it hangs forever.
Does anybody know how can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1621336

A workaround is listed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1621336/comments/4

Adding the workaround from Axel Kämpfe since the links seems to be broken:

1. Start a rootshell with "sudo -i"
2. Run `echo "bash -c 'service snapd.boot-ok start'" | at now + 4 min`
3. Then run `apt install snapd` (if it argues about canceled dpkg processes use the `dpkg --configure -a`. Then wait for at least 4 minutes. The hanging should gone then.

Good luck! :)

/Patrik

Comment: Dead links. When linking always include the relevant portion of the link inside the answer itself.

Comment: Good point. Found the original post via google cache. You're welcome.

Comment: @PatrikJ Since I have new linux vm , when i run "echo "bash -c 'service snapd.boot-ok start'" | at now + 4 min"  , it said "at" is not found and when I try to install it , it said you should run "dpkg --configure -a" which is hangs forever , it's like im in infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem twice and I have noticed that it happens everytime my system wants to upgrade to a new Kernel. The steps below seem to work for me all the time;

1. Boot into the recovery mode of your newest kernel versions.
2. Log-in to the system as root from the drop-down menu.
3. Edit the /etc/resolv.conf file using a text editor, I normally use vi, i.e.

   ```
   vi /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   and put in the contents below and save file;

   ```
   nameserver 208.67.222.220
   nameserver 208.67.222.222
   ```
4. After the above step, Ctrl+D (exit) back into the recovery mode menu and click on networking to enable network/internet connection.
5. Next, click on the dpkg item to fix broken packages.

That's it, after the reboot your system should have the right kernel install and broken packages fixed/removed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the application that is causing the `dpkg --configure -a` hanging error.

**Example:** `snapd`

2. Execute the following command:

> sudo apt-get remove snapd

In my case, I entered the following command:

> sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-8.0

3. Re-install the application if necessary.

I hope this helps you too. Health!